# passing access and secret key aws cli

Tags: aws-cli

I am trying to embed access and secret key along with aws cli. e.g.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --aws-access-key <access_key> --aws-secret-key <secret_key>
```

Also tried with -o and -w options for access and secret key respectively. It says : Unknown option aws-access-key and aws-secret-key

Answer (score 152):

You can provide keys on the command line via envars:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ABCD AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=EF1234 aws ec2 describe-instances
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#credentials

EDIT: @wisbucky noted this could leave secrets in your command history. One way around this in bash at least I think is to prepend your command with a blank space and the command should not propagate to your bash history.

Comment: Just be wary that would record your keys in your command history.

Comment: did the above syntax work  for anyone. I have searched enough but could not locate a working example of the recommended IAM Role as per the best practice

Comment: See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115917/why-is-bash-not-storing-commands-that-start-with-spaces?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for how to not save it in bash history

Comment: It doesn't address the specific question but assumes the over-arching solution. It works, but it throws off solution searches. I'm looking for the specific answer.

Comment: Prepending with a blank space will only omit it from your BASH history if that is configured. Not all BASH environemnts are configured to omit commands from the history prepended with a space.

Comment: "You must specify a region."

Comment: Note that you may also need to ignore the AWS credential (and possibly config) file environment variables, as in `AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE="" AWS_CONFIG_FILE="" AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ABCD AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=EF1234 aws ec2 describe-instances`, since those take precedence when obtaining the credentials.

Comment: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`  & `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are case sensitive switches; using lower case causes the CLI to fall back to the default credentials.

Answer (score 71):

You can set credentials with:

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id <yourAccessKey>
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key <yourSecretKey>
```

Verify your credentials with:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

For more information on set command:

```
aws configure set help
```

General pattern is:

```
aws <command> help
aws <command> <subcommand> help
```

Note: Before overriding your credentials, you may want to keep a copy of it:

```
aws configure get aws_access_key_id
aws configure get aws_secret_access_key
```

Comment: How can I set a role_arn to be assumed by the profile from AWS CLI? Its possible? I want to invoke a lambda function from awscli container but it return `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Access denied`. Any idea?

Answer (score 23):

I think the previous answers are correct, here is my response which is more like Danh response but also including multiple options and Windows too

### Linux/Mac

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_key; export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret;  aws s3 ls
```

### Another way to skin a cat for Linux/Mac

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_key AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret aws s3 ls
```

### Windows Powershell

```
$Env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="your_key"
$Env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="your_secret"
aws s3 ls
```

Full credit to great [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html)

Answer (score 14):

I had to access multiple accounts on Amazon. My solution:

Under `~/.aws/config`:

```
[default] 
aws_access_key_id=xxxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxx
region=sa-east-1
output=text
 
[profile prof1]
region=us-east-1 
output=text 
aws_access_key_id=yyy
aws_secret_access_key=yyyyy

[profile prof2] 
region=us-east-1 
output=text 
aws_access_key_id=wwwwww 
aws_secret_access_key=wwwww
```

...and then when evoke the AWS CLI, I passed the parameter `--profile` as follows:

```
/usr/local/bin/aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-xxxx --profile prof2
```

Comment: This helped me, but I had to store my credentials and region in a file called credentials, rather than config.

Answer (score 13):

Summarizing the [aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html), there several ways to pass credentials to the command line. Please note that there are no command line options to pass in the the key and secret key directly. The "provider chain" is used instead.

In my bash scripts, I often use environment variables. To add a tiny bit of security, I source a file containing the variables rather than putting them in the script. With named profiles, it's even easier.

The provider chain is:

1. command line options: specify region, output format, or **profile**
2. Environment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
3. The AWS credentials file – located at ~/.aws/credentials on Linux,
   macOS, or Unix, or at C:\Users\USERNAME .aws\credentials on
   Windows. This file can contain multiple named profiles in addition
   to a default profile.
4. The CLI configuration file – typically located at ~/.aws/config on
   Linux, macOS, or Unix, or at C:\Users\USERNAME .aws\config on
   Windows. This file can contain a default profile, named profiles,
   and CLI specific configuration parameters for each.
5. Container credentials – provided by Amazon Elastic Container Service
   on container instances when you assign a role to your task.
6. Instance profile credentials – these credentials can be used on EC2
   instances with an assigned instance role, and are delivered through
   the Amazon EC2 metadata service.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use aws configure:

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 2):

Its the best way and more secure to use IAM roles. There you can set specific rights to this instance and what it has to access in your account.

Depending on what awscli version you use you can use describe-instances in a couple ways.

Like this one:

```
ec2din -O your-key -W your-secret-key --region your-region
```

Also there is a big difference when you install awscli with pip install or from pkg like ubuntu deb package.

**ec2din** is a short command to **ec2-describe-instances**

More examples here: [ec2-describe-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeInstances.html)

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To access aws through cli,

```
aws configure
```

Comment: in PHP: 
putenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXX");
putenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX");

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use `echo` with aws configure as a one-liner:

```
echo -ne '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n' <access_key> <security_key> <region> <output> | aws configure
```

Answer (score -1):

You should store your credentials to ~/.aws/config file (or .aws/credentials)

More info how to setup it http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/index.html

Also as alternative way you can create IAM role and certain policy and set it to you ec2 instance where you will use aws cli, then you won't need any credentials setup there

Comment: You can also store multiple profiles in the .aws/credentials file and reference them with: 
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile profile-name

Answer (score -1):

Use the access key and id is not recommended as it will be stored in config file. Better approach is to create an IAM role and give required access which you need.

Comment: This works only when you use it on EC2 instances or other AWS resources, for other cases, like CI integration, you still need to have an API token